# JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) / While json parameter include

Tags: python, api

I'm trying to retrieve data from https://clinicaltrials.gov/ and althought I've specified the format as Json  in the request parameter:

```
fmt=json
```

the returned value is txt by default.

As a consequence i'm not able to retrieve the response in json()

Good:

```
import requests
response = requests.get('https://clinicaltrials.gov/api/query/study_fields?expr=heart+attack&fields=NCTId%2CBriefTitle%2CCondition&min_rnk=1&max_rnk=&fmt=json')
response.text
```

Not Good:

```
import requests
response = requests.get('https://clinicaltrials.gov/api/query/study_fields?expr=heart+attack&fields=NCTId%2CBriefTitle%2CCondition&min_rnk=1&max_rnk=&fmt=json')
response.json()
```

Any idea how to turn this txt to json ?

I've tried with response.text which is working but I want to retrieve data in Json()

Comment: I can't reproduce, `response.json()` returns a JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following code snippet:

```
import requests, json
response = requests.get('https://clinicaltrials.gov/api/query/study_fields?expr=heart+attack&fields=NCTId%2CBriefTitle%2CCondition&min_rnk=1&max_rnk=&fmt=json')
jsonResponse = json.loads(response.content)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [JSON package](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_json.asp) (that is built-in python, so you don't need to install anything), that will convert the text into a python object (dictionary) using the `json.loads()` function. [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_json.asp) you can find some examples.